# Can only use Oracle user when logged in as SYSDBA

Tags: oracle, users

I've just been setting up Oracle 19c on my Windows 10 Pro desktop following a hard drive failure. The install itself went well and I could log in with `/ as sysdba` fine, but every user I seem to add gets a `ORA-01017` error when I try to log in via SQLPlus or Oracle SQL Developer.

The username and password I'm entering are definitely correct as I'm able to grant SYSDBA to them, in which case, they can log in fine.

How can I find out what is stopping the users from being able to log in unless they have SYSDBA privs?

I've done the usuals like granting create session etc. I don't recall Oracle being this finicky the last time I set it up. I vaguely recall you had to prefix users with C## as databases are containerised these days but don't remember having to do anything else special, it all just worked.

I used this video for the install if it makes any difference:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hnpmy2kB5Mo

**UPDATE**

OK, thanks for those comments - that is helpful. A few things I've noticed:

1 - Sysdba

This seems to be a red herring. I can literally use any username & password (whether I've created it or not) and it will sign me in.

2 - Pluggable database is now up

I'd noticed that this was down on occasion when I ran `show pdbs` which obviously isn't ideal!

3 - I'd wrongly assumed that the c## prefix was just syntactic sugar for referring to the same pluggable database user at the container level. When I was tinkering with this before, I must have just got lucky when I created the user. I've created a bunch of container and pluggable users now so I think I have a better idea of how this works.

In particular, I'm getting these errors when I try to set up the user at the wrong level:

```
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name
ORA-65094: invalid local user or role name
```

This didn't mean a lot to me at the time but it is making more sense now.

At the moment I'm just trying to get a few tables stood for an application Proof Of Concept so I'm not primarily concerned with how the users are set up just yet (and we have Oracle bods who will be setting this up for us anyway).

Comment: Are you creating local users in a pluggable database, or common users in the container database? Please give examples of your SQL connection command, create user DDL, and any other SQL commands you are issuing in the process of creating users. Please be clear which database your are connecting to in your example.

Comment: Your comment about needing C## prefixed users is only relevant if you are trying to use those users for the CDB$ROOT container, which you shouldn't be doing except for niche management cases. Most usage should be through your own PDBs, have you double checked that's where your connection strings are pointing to? From your `sysdba` session you should be able to query `select con_id user_con_id, username, sys_context('userenv','CON_ID') my_con_id from cdb_users where username = '<MY USER>'` (replacing <MY USER> for the user you wish to connect to).